# Web Forms User Control Null Fields on Load

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, webforms

I am attempting to migrate an older ASP.NET **Web Site** project over to become a **Web Application** project in VS2010. It mostly appears to work, however I am finding that **User Controls** in *.ascx* files have all their own controls set as null.

I suspect it has something to do with how I am using declarations in the aspx files that need the controls, but I am uncertain. I created a sample file and page and can reproduce it. The original site was dynamically compiled, however I am trying turn it into a single DLL since nothing will ever change without a new deployment.

Can anyone give a reason why the "TheTextBox" would be null on Page_Load of the user control, and possible solution?

Control ASCX File *WebUserControl1.ascx*

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyNamespace.Ascx.WebUserControl1" ClassName="MyNamespace.Ascx.WebUserControl1" %>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TheTextBox" MaxLength="128" />
```

Control ASCX CodeFile *WebUserControl1.ascx.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MyNamespace.Ascx
{
    public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             // TheTextBox is null at this point. Why?
        }
    }
}
```

Control ASCX AutoGenerated Designer File *WebUserControl1.ascx.designer.cs*

```
namespace MyNamespace.Ascx {


    public partial class WebUserControl1 {

        /// <summary>
        /// TheTextBox control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox TheTextBox;
    }
}
```

WebForm Containing the Control *WebForm1.aspx*

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="MyNamespace.WebForm1" Codebehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" %>

<%@ Register NameSpace="MyNamespace.Ascx" Assembly="MyAssembly"  TagPrefix="prefix" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageHead" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <prefix:WebUserControl1 runat="server" ID="IncludedControl" />
</asp:Content>
```

WebForm Containing the Control CodeFile *WebForm1.aspx.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: As suggested, replacing the WebForm directive with

```
<%@ Register Src="~/ascx/WebUserControl1.ascx" TagName="WebUserControl1" TagPrefix="prefix" %>
```

results in a lovely Yellow Screen of Death:

*CS0260: Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'PSVOnline.Ascx.WebUserControl1'; another partial declaration of this type exists*

```
Line 129:    
Line 130:    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGlobalScopeAttribute()]
Line 131:    public class WebUserControl1 : global::MyNamespace.Ascx.WebUserControl1 {
Line 132:        
Line 133:        private static bool @__initialized;
```

Answer (score 4):

Typically when I register a user control, instead of what you have on WebForm1.aspx I register them like so:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/WebUserControl1.ascx" TagName="control" TagPrefix="uc" %>
```

I don't know if that's the problem you're having, but that doesn't look like the typical way to register a user control.

Comment: I did have this approach with the user controls in question. In the case of the migrated application, the user were controls were complaining of duplicate classes. This seemed to happen because the control was compiled into the site DLL, and the ALSO compiled again on execution. Only way around that I could think of was having it in a separate class, which I haven't tried yet.

Comment: This post saved me, i have just stupidly forgot about control declaration :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution..

Using the following approach works perfectly..

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASP2UserControlLibrary.aspx